# How can I change the title of an android activity based on the Fragment in ViewPager2/TabView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am working on an app and when I slide to the next tab I would like to change the title of the screen to match the Tab!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `registerOnPageChangeCallback` in `ViewPager2` to detect page swipes. In `ViewPager2`s host(for example host Activity) implement this event and when `onPageSelected` is called change the title of host `Activity`. In `onPageSelected` method you can get current position of `ViewPager2` and based on position set your title.

```java
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);

        // Set title of Activity based on the position of Fragment
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
    }
});
```